# Bind arguments to input function passed to lodash's "debounce"

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using reactjs. In, one of my component's class, I have a function to which I would like to bind the 'this' object and also to **an argument**. It is:

```
    const boundSingleClick = this.onSingleClick.bind(this, myArgument)
```

onSingleClick signature and definition:

```
    onSingleClick(itemId) {
      this.clickedOnce = undefined
      this.props.previewItem(itemId)
    }
```

Now, I would like to use this function in lodash's debounce. I'm using it this way:

```
    const delayedClick = _.debounce(boundSingleClick, 300)
    delayedClick()
```

What I notice when the debounced function is invoked, is that, the 'myArgument' parameter is 'undefined' in the function call - though, 'this' is properly bound.

Does debounce accept functions with bound parameters as it's argument ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your onSingleClick function's signature

Comment: Can you check what is the value of myArgument when call bind on onSingleClick? Is it the expected value or is it undefined?

Comment: I meant to say that what is the value of myArgument where you bind the function and not when the function is invoked by _.debounce

Comment: Apologies, I misread you, it has a valid value. There is another function onDoubleClick which I'm not debouncing - that also has a valid value when I'm binding it and when it is invoked. Only debounced function has the issue.

Comment: Post up your code in situ please

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep the comment numbers low on the OP, I am posting this as an answer but this is more like a quickfix/workaround and maybe someone else could point us to the real problem as I am unable to reproduce the bug on my side.

Try invoking the boundSingleClick as:

```
const delayed = _.debounce((...args) => boundSingleClick.apply(null, args), 300)
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. My code had a mistake because of which I was facing issues. Debounce works fine with bound parameters. Thanks for your help, it helped correct my code.